TomlError installing pymongo using pip
When installing pymongo in virtualenv I'm getting this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 315, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 131, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 294, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 240, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 349, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 109, in prep_for_dist
    self.req.load_pyproject_toml()
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 485, in load_pyproject_toml
    pep517_data = load_pyproject_toml(
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_internal/pyproject.py", line 66, in load_pyproject_toml
    pp_toml = pytoml.load(f)
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_vendor/pytoml/parser.py", line 11, in load
    return loads(fin.read(), translate=translate, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, filename=getattr(fin, 'name', repr(fin)))
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_vendor/pytoml/parser.py", line 24, in loads
    ast = _p_toml(src, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook)
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_vendor/pytoml/parser.py", line 340, in _p_toml
    s.expect_eof()
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_vendor/pytoml/parser.py", line 125, in expect_eof
    return self._expect(self.consume_eof())
  File "/Users/shwetanka/projects/templatemgmt/preview/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_vendor/pytoml/parser.py", line 165, in _expect
    raise TomlError('msg', self._pos[0], self._pos[1], self._filename)
pip._vendor.pytoml.core.TomlError: /private/var/folders/3c/fdcxlx_n3bs_m59lr1fwvqsh0000gn/T/pip-install-oorxgore/pymongo/pyproject.toml(203, 1): msg

I tried pip3 install pymongo and pip3 install pymongo --no-use-pep517
When I install without virtual environment it works. I installed other packages and those worked.
